# How to detect whether the route is the current route in its build method

Tags: dart, flutter

I use `FutureBuilder` in my routes, which displays data after getting data from database.

I found that when I open the second route, the build method of home route was called even home route is not the current route. However, I hope the build method does not get data if home route isn't the current one.

That's the code I try to implement:

```
class HomeRoute extends StatefulWidget { State<StatefulWidget> createState() => HomeRouteState(); }

class HomeRouteState extends State<HomeRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    //...
    drawer: Drawer(
      //  There is a ListTile that can push SecondRoute
    ),
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: _getData(),
     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {/* ... */}
    ),
  );

  _getData() async {
    if(/* this route is the current one */) {
      //  get data
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to prevent the `build()` of your home page from getting called when it is not visible. Here is what you can try.

```
bool _isHomeVisible = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return _isHomeVisible ? YourWidgetImplementation() : Container();
}
```

And before you navigate do this.

```
void _navigateToNewPage() {
  _isHomeVisible = false; // going to new page, make it false
  Navigator.push(...).then((_) {
    _isHomeVisible = true; // coming back to home page, make it true
  });
}
```